# Is there a term for the fallacy of making an inverse inference?

Tags: logic

Suppose for example that I am playing a poker game with my friend who’s never played before. He gets a royal flush on his first hand. I think “there’s no way, this must be rigged by him.”

I make an inference from “He gets a royal flush” to “He rigged it to win.”  Now, of course, this inference isn’t necessarily true. Although the chances of this are low, I might observe the circumstances of the game, and observe there’s atleast no direct evidence of rigging. But at the end of the day, the low chance of him getting a royal flush on his first try seems suspect.

After all, if he rigged it to get a royal flush, it would necessarily imply he would get a royal flush.

The last inference is an inverse of the first one. I have noticed that people often conflate the two such as with conspiracies: “if the vaccines didn’t work, some would die despite the vaccine” vs. “if some die despite the vaccine, the vaccine doesn’t work”

Comment: in what way do you think people conflate them? the first looks like an inference to the best explanation of a royal flush, whereas in the second a rigged hand, it is inferred, brings about a royal flush. IBE does not involve deductive inference, so i'm guessing it won't be a formal fallacy. if you include both explanandum and explanans in your inferences, then what's the fallacy? sometimes we infer the cause from the effect, sometimes vice versa.

Comment: Not clear... But yes: "if P, then Q" does **not** imply "if Q, then P".

Comment: The term is [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent):"a formal fallacy of taking a true conditional statement (e.g., "If the lamp were broken, then the room would be dark"), and invalidly inferring its converse ("The room is dark, so the lamp is broken"), even though that statement may not be true." However, in informal contexts of plausible reasoning this isn't necessarily a fallacy, see [inference to the best explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning).

Answer (score 1):

1. P implies Q [conditional/implication]
2. Q implies P [converse]
3. ~P implies ~Q [inverse]
4. ~Q implies ~P [contrapositive]

1 and 4 are logically equivalent and so are 2 and 3

R = game is rigged

F = Friend gets a royal flush on the first try

A) R implies F

B) F implies R

A and B are the converse of each other; most importantly, they're not logically equivalent.

*Inverse fallacy/denying the antecdent fallacy*

1. p implies q
2. ~p

Ergo,

3. ~q

*Converse fallacy/affirming the consequent fallacy*

This is fallacy you're commiting.

1. p implies q
2. q

Ergo,

3. p

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of these things are deductive but just inductive. So it's possible, likely or unlikely not true or false.

So yes from an unlikely chance of something happening you could conjecture that foul play happened. And the more rare the event the more likely the foul play. But you don't prove anything by that and could still be wrong.

And it's technically not a wrong or a fallacy to follow that:

- If A causes B
- then if B. A was possibly the cause

Now if you'd said that with certainty and made the deductive conclusion that A MUST be the cause, then that would be a fallacy because just because from A follows B doesn't mean that from B follows A. B could follow from A,C,D,E,F,... and so if you see B there's a whole alphabet of reasons for that other than A. But if you're just reasoning with probabilities, then it's not wrong to see that as an option. The only fallacy would be to think that because it was so plainly obvious (just inverse the inference) that it must also be highly likely, which it doesn't have to be.

Also just some nitpicking on the example in order to mention some other options for this scenario:

A rigged game doesn't necessarily imply a royal flush. Winning by a high card would be way better because less suspicious or giving your opponent a flush and yourself a full house. As they're certain to win, they are likely to bet high and still lose. A royal flush is 100% win but it's not how you would rig a game. If you had full access you could make that way more subtle only being obvious by winning too often and even if you can only rig your own cards you'd likely just increase the odds not win with certainty. So if someone is such a bad cheater, how likely is it that they are cheating?
Also why should they rig that game if it's their first ever attempt and there's nothing to be won by doing so?